# Converting Crystal Reports to SSRS Issue

Tags: reporting-services, crystal-reports, ssrs-2008, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-xi

Hi I am converting the crystal report to the SSRS reporting but i am new to both the reporting tools in crystal report there is lots of fields that are calculate but i am stuck at this one field is calculate like ,

```
"!" & {MM.JobNumber} & "!"
```

and i am not sure what it does so any insights would be very great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information provided, this formula simply concatenates two exclamation marks onto the field {MM.Jobnumber}.

The output for this would look something like this

```
!Jobnumbervalue!
```

If you haven't tried already, http://www.crystalmigrater.com/Default.aspx is an extremely useful tool for what you are trying to accomplish.